# How can I detect the language/typeface of a text; to use the correct font? Or can someone suggest me a different font to use?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fonts

I want to support many languages of the world, to be precise: over 150 different languages (tbh I support all languages that google translator supports). For that I use Google's Font Family Noto: https://fonts.google.com/noto

˜800 languages are covered with the font Noto Sans. But other ˜200 languages like Japanese and Korean, require dedicated fonts like Noto Sans Japanese or Noto Sans Korean.

The problem is: e.g: an english user (living in New York, but immigrated from Tokyo) (who uses Noto Sans because he uses my app in english), sees Japanese content because he follows japanese users. If I render now the japanese text with Noto Sans, he will either see weird glyphs like ▯▯▯▯▯▯▯▯▯ or his app will crash.

Of course I don't want that. I have to detect that the text is Japanese, and render the text with its correct font.

Can someone suggest me a javascript library (that detects languages/typefaces) that works on the browser with React, but also with React Native on Android/iOS? Or maybe just another font that looks like Roboto/Noto/Helvetica, but supports many languages?

thanks in advance!

edit second question: What should I do if a japanese guy uses japanese kanji/kata/hira and english in one sentence? how to deal with that?

Answer (score 0):

you need get header request  which language is has oky

Accept-Language: 
Accept-Language: *